# How do fields change when you transform spacetime coordinates?

Tags: field-theory, coordinate-systems, calculus

In field theory, I have seen the notion that when you infinitessimaly transform your coordinates in the form $$x'_\mu = x_\mu + \delta x_\mu$$

The fields transform as
$$\phi(x) \rightarrow \phi'(x') =\phi(x) + \delta\phi(x) + \partial_\mu\phi x^\mu$$

Why do the fields transform this way? I am a bit confused about what $\phi'(x')$ really means here. Isn't $\phi'$ *already* the transformed field after you perform the coordinate transformation? Why isn't it something like $\phi(x') = \phi(x) + \delta\phi(x) + \partial_\mu\phi x^\mu$, where instead on the LHS you have an unprimed field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should distinguish between two different things:

1. We can define a new field by $\phi'(x)\equiv \phi(x+\delta x)$. Then $\phi'(x)$ and $\phi(x)$ are two different configurations of the scalar field, both expresed in the same coordinate system.
2. Wwe can write the original field $\phi$ in a new coordinate system: $\phi'(x')\equiv\phi(x)$. Then $\phi'(x')$ and $\phi(x)$ both describe the same configuration of the scalar field, expressed in two different coordinate systems. This is the case shown in the question.

This might be a little more clear if we write $x(p)$ for the coordinates of the point $p$. Then the two cases above look like this:

1. $\phi'(x(p))= \phi(x(p'))$
2. $\phi'(x'(p)) = \phi(x(p))$.

In the first case, $x(p')$ is a new point expressed in the original coordinate system. In the second case, $x'(p)$ is the original point expressed in a new coordinate system. The second case is the one shown in the question. Both cases define a new function $\phi'$ of the list of coordinates (list of real numbers), but only the first case defines a new function of spacetime (function of $p$). In the second case, we're just writing the same function of spacetime (function of $p$) in two different ways.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I do find it more clear for me expressing it in terms of $x(p)$, but even so I am still having trouble visualizing what an object like $\phi(x(p))$ is really saying. I suppose my naive conception coming into this is that $x$ is the point, and $\phi$ is the field AT that point. If say $x(p)$, how should I intuitively be thinking of $x$ as a function of $p$ in this context?

Comment: @physics_fan_123 In four-dimensional spacetime, $x(p)=\big(x_0(p),\,x_1(p),\,x_2(p),\,x_3(p)\big)$ are the four coordinates of the point $p$. We're expressing the field as a function of the coordinates (a function of four real variables), but the coordinates are in turn a function of the point. The point $p$ is not a real number or a set of real numbers; it's a more abstract concept. In any given coordinate system, different points have different coordinates, so the $x_\mu$s are a function of $p$.